# Apache reports status 200 but file doesn't exist in the server

Tags: apache-2.2, http, logging, http-status-code

In Apache access log I have these lines repeating all over the file:

```
186.44.190.132 - - [22/Feb/2013:23:41:34 +0100] "POST /includes/wishlistcwh.php HTTP/1.1" 200 42416 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
151.246.16.245 - - [22/Feb/2013:23:41:32 +0100] "POST /includes/wishlistcwh.php HTTP/1.1" 200 42416 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
186.44.190.132 - - [22/Feb/2013:23:41:40 +0100] "POST /includes/wishlistcwh.php HTTP/1.1" 200 42416 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
```

It's an attack to the website, but the thing is that "/includes/wishlistcwh.php" doesn't exist in the server and Apache is returning 200 status.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules to handle requests for files that don't exist?

Comment: Yep, that's what I missed.. Now it's returning 404. Thanks.

Comment: I'll make that an answer instead of a comment then, so the question doesn't end up in the unanswered section of the site.

Comment: You're right! Sorry

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about, if I'd been sure that was the problem I'd have made it an answer instead of a comment right away :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you have a mod_rewrite rule that handles requests for files that don't exist.